# ¿Se puede usar una variable como inicio de un ciclo for?

Tags: java

Tengo este código pero al cuando ingreso una prueba de 2000 ,como inicio, y 8000 ,como final, no muestra ningún resultado que podría hacer.

```
int ini,fin;
        do {                
            System.out.println("Ingrese el inicio y final de la serie");
            ini=entrada.nextInt();
            fin=entrada.nextInt();
            if (ini>fin) {
                System.out.println("ERROR! Valor de inicio es mayor al final");
            }
        } while (ini>fin);
        for (int i=ini; i <= fin; i++) {
            if (cubo(i)) {
                System.out.println(i);
            }
        }
```

Esta es la funcion que tengo

```
public static boolean cubo(long num){
    int rc;
    rc=(int) Math.pow(num,(double)1.0/3.0);
    if(rc*rc*rc==num){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Si no imprime nada es porque `cubo(i)`  devuelve falso. Revisa eso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que el problema es que la función cubo siempre te devuelve falso por culpa de la pérdida de precisión. Si usas double, la precisión de Java es la misma que la que tiene, por ejemplo, Javascript:

```js
const raiz = 15;
const alCubo = 15 **3;
console.log(raiz,'al cubo es', alCubo);

const raizCalculada = alCubo ** (1/3);

console.log('La raíz cúbica de',alCubo,'es', raizCalculada);
```

Para no perder precisión, haz tus cálculos usando la clase [`BigDecimal`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigDecimal.html), que está diseñada para ser todo precisa que sea necesario en los cálculos matemáticos.

Comment: Muchas gracias lo cambie al codigo para usarlo en Java y me funcion perfectamente